# I can't understand why in log show unnecessary information

Tags: java, logging, thymeleaf

when the application is launched, an unnecessary log is displayed, and it is unclear to me where it comes from, in pom.xml there is no logger dependency, this message appears starting after I added the logger to pom.xml , then deleted, but the logger only for [THYMELEAF] remained

```
log:
[2022-11-11 02:26:14,343] Artifact al_project1:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2022-11-11 02:26:14,343] Artifact al_project1:war: Deploy took 7,112 milliseconds
11.11.2022 14:26:15.931 [http-nio-8082-exec-1] DEBUG o.t.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF] INITIALIZING TEMPLATE ENGINE
11.11.2022 14:26:16.222 [http-nio-8082-exec-1] DEBUG o.t.T.CONFIG - Initializing Thymeleaf Template engine configuration...
[THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE CONFIGURATION:
[THYMELEAF] * Thymeleaf version: 3.0.15.RELEASE (built 2022-01-31T00:00:31+0000)
[THYMELEAF] * Cache Manager implementation: org.thymeleaf.cache.StandardCacheManager
[THYMELEAF] * Template resolvers:
[THYMELEAF]     * org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Message resolvers:
[THYMELEAF]     * org.thymeleaf.spring5.messageresolver.SpringMessageResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Link builders:
[THYMELEAF]     * org.thymeleaf.linkbuilder.StandardLinkBuilder
[THYMELEAF] * Dialect: SpringStandard (org.thymeleaf.spring5.dialect.SpringStandardDialect)
[THYMELEAF]     * Prefix: "th"
[THYMELEAF]     * Processors for Template Mode: HTML
[THYMELEAF]         * Element Tag Processors by [matching element and attribute name] [precedence]:
[THYMELEAF]             * [* {th:include,data-th-include}] [100]: org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardIncludeTagProcessor
[THYMELEAF]             * [* {th:insert,data-th-insert}] [100]: org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardInsertTagProcessor
[THYMELEAF]             * [* {th:replace,data-th-replace}] [100]: org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardReplaceTagProcessor
[THYMELEAF]             * [* {th:substituteby,data-th-substituteby}] [100]: org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardSubstituteByTagProcessor
[THYMELEAF]             * [* {th:each,data-th-each}] [200]: org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardEachTagProcessor
[THYMELEAF]             * [* {th:switch,data-th-switch}] [250]: org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardSwitchTagProcessor
[THYMELEAF]             * [* {th:case,data-th-case}] [275]: org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardCaseTagProcessor
[THYMELEAF]             * [* {th:if,data-th-if}] [300]: org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardIfTagProcessor
[THYMELEAF]             * [* {th:unless,data-th-unless}] [400]: org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardUnlessTagProcessor
.......
[THYMELEAF]         * #httpServletRequest
[THYMELEAF]         * #httpSession
[THYMELEAF]         * #fields
[THYMELEAF]         * #themes
[THYMELEAF]         * #mvc
[THYMELEAF]         * #requestdatavalues
[THYMELEAF]     * Execution Attributes:
[THYMELEAF]         * "StandardExpressionParser": Standard Expression Parser
[THYMELEAF]         * "StandardJavaScriptSerializer": org.thymeleaf.standard.serializer.StandardJavaScriptSerializer@453e1f4
[THYMELEAF]         * "StandardCSSSerializer": org.thymeleaf.standard.serializer.StandardCSSSerializer@3f982a20
[THYMELEAF]         * "EnableSpringELCompiler": true
[THYMELEAF]         * "StandardVariableExpressionEvaluator": SpringEL
[THYMELEAF]         * "StandardConversionService": org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SpringStandardConversionService@2395c904
[THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE CONFIGURED OK
11.11.2022 14:26:16.347 [http-nio-8082-exec-1] DEBUG o.t.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE INITIALIZED
```

```
pom.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>spring.audiolessons.18_10.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_audiolessons_18_10_webapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>spring_audiolessons_18_10_webapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

    <spring.version>5.3.23</spring.version>
    <encoding.type>UTF-8</encoding.type>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.9.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.9.0</junit.platform.version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>${encoding.type}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${encoding.type</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <file.encoding>${encoding.type}</file.encoding>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.15.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.6.Final</version> <!--8.0.0.Final - Bullshit-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.12</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>spring_audiolessons_18_10_webapp</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (maybe moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I tried to remove all log dependencies and the configuration log file, the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Create a logger configuration and set log-level for org.thymeleaf to INFO (at least)